# how can parallel exec command running

Tags: tcl

i have this script and want to run the exec in parallel. at the moment it is running one after another. How do I do that?

Many thanks for your help

```
bind pub -|- !tt proc:tt
proc proc:tt {nick host handle channel arg} {

set search [lindex [split [stripcodes bcu $arg]] 0]

foreach name {name1 name2 name3 name4 name5} {
    set results [exec sh search.sh $name $search]
putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :results: $results"
}
}
```

at the moment the issue is in succession. but it should be parallel

```
[24.02.20/22:00:59] <testbot> results: /home/test/name1
[24.02.20/22:01:34] <testbot> results: /home/test/name2
[24.02.20/22:03:05] <testbot> results: /home/test/name3
[24.02.20/22:09:05] <testbot> results: /home/test/name4
[24.02.20/22:09:07] <testbot> results: /home/test/name5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a command in the background *and capture the results,* you need to open a pipeline and run things asynchronously. (The `exec` command can run things in the background if `&` is its final argument, but not while capturing the results.)

```
bind pub -|- !tt proc:tt
proc proc:tt {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set search [lindex [split [stripcodes bcu $arg]] 0]

    foreach name {name1 name2 name3 name4 name5} {
        # Launch the subprocess
        set pipe [open |[list sh search.sh $name $search]]
        # Set up a handler for when the subprocess produces *any* output *or* finishes
        fconfigure $pipe readable [list handle:search:output $channel $pipe $name]
    }
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel processing..."
}
proc handle:search:output {channel pipe name} {
    set line [gets $pipe]
    if {[eof $pipe]} {
        close $pipe
        putnow "PRIVMSG $channel search for $name done"
        return
    }
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :result($name): $line"
}
```

Note that this launches all the searches in parallel. This might load your system up quite a bit! This may also deliver results in an arbitrary order. Doing things in order *is* possible, but requires either more complicated code with manual continuation passing, or coroutines (Tcl 8.6 or later). Or you can hand off the doing things in sequence to a subprocess: that's easy.

Comment: i have this error : Tcl error: bad option "readable": should be one of -blocking, -buffering, -buffersize, -encoding, -eofchar, or -translation

Comment: A typo by Donal. Change `fconfigure` to `fileevent`\

Comment: I still get an error on Partyline about 50 times: BOGUS MESSAGE!

Comment: Donal Fellows have you a idea to fore the error BOGUS MESSAGE!?

Answer (score 0):

See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm

> If the last arg is `&` then the pipeline will be executed in background. In this case the exec command will return a list whose elements are the process identifiers for all of the subprocesses in the pipeline. The standard output from the last command in the pipeline will go to the application's standard output if it has not been redirected, and error output from all of the commands in the pipeline will go to the application's standard error file unless redirected.

Comment: where does that & go if it's in a variable? set results [exec sh search.sh $release $site ] & Tcl error: wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"

Comment: Mind argument positions: `&` is meant to terminate the nested command: `set results [exec ... &]`.

Comment: set results [exec sh search.sh $name $search & ] its error: Tcl error: missing value to go with key

Comment: As Donal said, you can't capture the output of a background exec, so my suggestion is the wrong approach.